# Binding UserControl property to parent data context

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a UserControl in a WPF MVVM application whose visibility I want to bind to a property in its parent's DataContext.  The problem is that the child UC has it's own DataContext.  So how do I use the child DataContext for the internals of the child UC and still use the parent DataContext for the visibility?

So for example, the DataContext of the parent control looks something like this

```
class Parent
{
    public Child Child { get; private set; }

    public Visibility ChildVisible
    {
        get { return Visibility.Visible; }
    }
}
```

In the XAML, how can I configure the Visibility binding so that it points to Parent.ControlVisible, instead of Child.ControlVisible?

```
<local:Child DataContext="{Binding Control}" Visibility="{Binding ControlVisible}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the parent user control by using ElementName, and use its DataContext, e.g.

```
<Border x:Name="parentControl" DataContext="{Binding Parent}" Visibility="Visible">

    <Border DataContext="{Binding Child}" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.MyVisibleProperty, ElementName=parentControl}">

    </Border>

</Border>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but the ElementName gives me the parent UserControl in the XAML, not the parent DataContext in the view model, right?

Comment: You are right. Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Visibility, ElementName=parentControl}"> - edited the answer

Comment: But this will set the child's visibility equal to the parent, which is not what I'm trying to do.  The parent in this case is always visible.  I just want the child's visibility determined by a property on the parent's data context.

Comment: In my example both parent and child were bound to the same property, and then their visibilities are equal. Changed my example.

Comment: The prefacing by "DataContext" was what I was missing before.  I was able to use this for your approach, as well as the one below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I use the child DataContext for the internals of the child UC

You should not set the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` (see [this](http://mutelight.org/datacontext-in-a-custom-control)). Therefore, use `RelativeResource` or `ElementName` in the Bindings in your child UserControl. Note that You can use the DataContext of the parent in your child UserControl.

Also, don't forget to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for the models and/or view models.

Comment: Good info.  While the visibility is working when using this approach, the binding is still not working yet.  On the child grid I used the following, but it seems to refer to the child, I think because both the parent and child are UserControls.  Is there a way to ensure it goes to the parent?   DataContext="{Binding Path=PropName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"

Comment: Use ``AnsestorLevel=2`` to bind to the second usercontrol.

Comment: Ok, that gets me back to the parent user control, but the property is actually on the parent's view model (data context).  Is there a way to tell it to bind to the property on the parent controls data context?

Comment: I was finally able to get it by prefacing the property name by "DataContext" on the grid of the child control as follows       <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext.PropName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl,AncestorLevel=2}}">.   Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.